# Como conseguir os arquivos de um repo do GitHub?

Tags: github

Estou fazendo um projeto que irá fazer  download de um Git do GitHub, porém, quero que o download seja automatizado ao usuário. Para isso, preciso conseguir o nome dos arquivos e das pastas que estão no diretório. Há algum arquivo em um repo que contenha os diretórios e os arquivos existentes em cada Git?

Comment: Eu sei que localmente isto fica na pasta `.git` e dentro do arquivo `index`.

Comment: Quer fazer isso do lado do servidor ou cliente?

Comment: @Sergio sempre, cliente. É uma aplicação de desktop em C++ com WinAPI.

Comment: Serve o link com o zip? `https://github.com/contaUtilizador/nomeProjeto/archive/master.zip`

Comment: @Sergio perfeito. Vou encontrar uma maneira de transformar o zip em pastas. Pode colocar o comentario como resposta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar-se o link que o github tem com o zip do projeto.

O formato é:

> https://github.com/**contaUtilizador**/**nomeProjeto**/archive/master.zip

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Baixando dinamicamente o zip para seu para o seu projeto através da url mencionada acima

```
https://github.com/contaUtilizador/nomeProjeto/archive/master.zip
```

Você pode extrair o zip e navegar livremente pelos diretórios, que já estarão no seu ambiente.

Comment: Essa resposta é a exata acima.